# Apache Samza does not run

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-samza

I am trying to set up a Apache Samza and Kafka environment. I am experiencing some problems when trying to run the modules.

I have Kafka working correctly but I can not make Samza work. I have installed two Debian Jeesy AMD64 boxes and followed the instructions of the Samza documentation:

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre git maven
git clone http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/samza.git
cd samza
./gradlew clean build
```

When I try to launch the script that should start the Yarn AppMaster with the script provided with Samza:

```
/opt/samza/samza-shell/src/main/bash/run-am.sh
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Main class org.apache.samza.job.yarn.SamzaAppMaster has not been found or loaded
```

If I try to run a test job with the run-job.sh script

```
./run-job.sh --config-factory=org.apache.samza.config.factories.PropertiesConfigFactory --config-path=file://$PWD/deploy/samza/config/wikipedia-feed.properties
```

and I get a similar error referencing the org.apache.samza.job.JobRunner class.

I am thinking that I have a java configuration issue, but I am not able to find much help or reference.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not working but I have gone one step ahead. When executing the Samza provided scripts from a path, they expect to be located in a /bin/ folder and they need to have a /lib/ one where all the samza .jar files should be located.

I am still having some dependencies issues, but different ones.